# Can't resolve Error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'bool' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'bool'

Tags: c++, overloading

I am trying to overload the less than operator, but I keep getting 
 Error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'bool' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'bool'.
 If it helps, the dv variable that I am trying to compare is an integer. Any help that y'all
 can give would be awesome! Thanks!!!

```
 //function declaration
 friend bool & operator < (const Vertex & v1, const Vertex & v2);

 ///function definition 
 bool & operator < (Vertex & v1, Vertex & v2)
 {
   return v1.getDV() > v2.getDV();
 }
```

Comment: Why are you returning a reference in the first place? What could the client have to gain from modifying it?

Comment: Because that's how I've always written overloaded functions and it's worked every time in the past...

Comment: Why is your function declaration different from definition? Why do you have `const` in the first but not in the second? This definition will not link with that declaration.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to return reference to `bool` from comparison operators. Just change the return type to `bool`.

And the compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong: you're trying to bind a non-`const` reference to a temporary. This, indeed, makes no sense: if you're going to return a non-`const` reference then you should return a reference to a value that's going to stick around so it can be modified later.

Comment: So change the variable dv's type from integer (how I originally declared it) to a bool?

Comment: Change the return value of `operator<` from `bool&` to `bool`.